# Language support

Tags: language-support, time

I recently installed latest version of Ubuntu 64bit. Work perfectly

During installation I specified English as my default language.
My time zone location is Qatar (Middle East).
In some instances I have Arabic script - on the date/Kcalc/file manager date.

I have tried selecting a different time zone but this does not resolve the problem.
Help  -- thx

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Regional Formats setting to some English option.

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-formats.html